# Getting page / post URL on publish and / or update

Tags: php, posts, functions, pages, hooks

I am trying to use a simple `publish_post / publish_page` hook to get the URL of the post/page when it is either published or updated so I can later turn it into a static page.

Is it possible to add this hook outside of the theme functions.php file, because this is far more preferable to me? I also am unsure how to grab the file location / URL from the result? Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution for you - this hook will send you a full URL to the post that is being published. Don't forget to update `your@email.com`

```
function post_published_notification( $ID, $post ) {
    $permalink = get_permalink( $ID ); // GETTING THE PERMALINK
    $to[] = 'your@email.com'; // UPDATE THIS

    $title = $post->post_title;
    $subject = sprintf( 'Published: %s', $title );
    $message = sprintf( 'View: %s', $permalink );
    wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, [] );
}
add_action( 'publish_post', 'post_published_notification', 10, 2 );
```

If you want it to work on post update as well, just add this action to the bottom of it:

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'post_published_notification', 10, 2 );
```

You can add this hooks to the bottom of your functions.php or in your plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you totally can add your code to some plugin/drop-in, instead `functions.php` in the theme. And you can use `get_permalink()` function to do that.

Comment: Do I need any sort of includes, though?

Comment: You can read about [WordPress Plugins](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugins) at their codex page. Or You can just make a script with code and include where you want.